# mysql 2 SELECT in one query

Tags: php, mysql, select, where-clause

I want these two SELECT queries to give one result and then i want to order it by `date_time`

SELECT 1:

```
"SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `f_id` = '$uid' AND `t_id` = '$pid'"
```

SELECT 2:

```
"SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `f_id` = '$pid' AND `t_id` = '$uid'"
```

I tried to put it in one WHERE clause but it's impossible, I also tried to put them in sub-query but that made SELECT 2 to join right SELECT 1 :/ I want ONE output array of these two queries, ordered by `date_time`.
How is it possible?

Comment: It's generally not recommended to use SELECT * in a query unless you really do need all the columns returned.  You're usually better off to identify the specific columns you want to use in the results to cut down on returning more than you really need.

Comment: I rolled back your edit that changed the question title.  No need to do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `f_id` = '$uid' AND `t_id` = '$pid'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `f_id` = '$pid' AND `t_id` = '$uid'
```

EDIT:

Er... sorry, I didn't see it is the same table.

```
SELECT * FROM table
  WHERE (`f_id` = '$uid' AND `t_id` = '$pid') OR (`f_id` = '$pid' AND `t_id` = '$uid')
  ORDER BY date_time
```

Comment: The other answers are actually the same :-)

Comment: i tried where clause with or but didn't worked for me
but union all does the job :D

Comment: The solution of @echo_me also has the sorting.

Answer (score 3):

What about:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    `table` 
WHERE 
    (`f_id` = '$uid' AND `t_id` = '$pid') OR 
    (`f_id` = '$pid' AND `t_id` = '$uid')
ORDER BY 
    `date_time` DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   SELECT * FROM 

      ( select * FROM `table` WHERE `f_id` = '$uid' AND `t_id` = '$pid'
       union all 
        SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `f_id` = '$pid' AND `t_id` = '$uid' )t

   ORDER BY date_time
```

Comment: what is the t for at the end?